# Are activation functions applied to feature maps?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, activation-functions, convolution

If I have a convolutional neural network, and I convolve my input tensor with a kernel, the output is a feature map. Is an activation function then applied to this feature map?

If its an image that is a 2D tensor, would the activation function change every single value on this image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is applied element-wise on every single value of the feature map.
Assuming ReLU as your nonlinearity function, all negative values of the image feature map are set to zero, and the rest of the elements stay unchanged.